# Android Service is running, but it doesn't show up in settings -> running services

Tags: android, service

I have a service in my app, as some other apps have, too. From what I am used to, I can see (and kill) services nicely in settings -> (running) services. But: not mine...

The service itself is extended from IntentService. It is handling Alarm Intents via BroadcastReceiver and also messages from my app and back to do some work. As it's essential to my app and keeps some remote web session and other (read: "a lot of") persistent data, I do explicitly start it in main activity with

```
startService(new Intent(this, HeartBeatService.class));
```

and in the service, I even use

```
startForeground(NOTIFY_RUNNING, runNotification);
```

Other of my apps' activities using the service just using bindService(), working like a charm.

It really *is* running. Perfectly and always, as I wished, even if the activities get killed by android because of whatever android thinks it's good for.

Just: I don't "see" it running. 
I also tried overrriding the service onStartCommand() to return START_STICKY, but nothing changed. I know, this one should not be overwritten in IntentService.

Or am I just thinking wrong somehow? Is IntentService "different"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Android documentation reference:

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Your service will only run when it receives an intent and stops once it is done doing what that intent had it do.

Also, I've found that services bound to activities will not show up in the running services screen.

Once you remove the binding, they show up.

Comment: Reading and understanding what's written sometimes should help... I guess I just was thinking totally wrong. I will refactor the class to standard Service and just call my old IntentService.onHandleIntent() in a new Thread Runnable from onStartCommand(). Let's see what happens... Gonna report later...

Comment: Refactured as Service instead IntentService, working same, PLUS getting displayed now in app services ;)
But I really wonder, because overwriting the onStartCommand() with returning START_STICKY should have done it, also. No idea. Thanks anyways for the pointer!