# Android: My service is not shown in Developer Options -> "running services"

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

My problem is that although I am running a foreground service, I cannot see it in "running services" within "developer options". Below are the details.

I am starting a Service from an Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getContext(), PilotForegroundService.class);
intent.putExtra(CALLSIGN, callsign);
this.getContext().startService(intent);
```

Inside `onStartCommand` I set it to foreground service (by calling `startForeground(...)` and I start an `AsyncTask` that runs forever (or until a condition is met in the `AsyncTask`). The code of `onStartCommand` is shown below:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        String callsign = intent.getExtras().getString(PilotFragment.CALLSIGN);
        startForeground(PilotForegroundAsyncTask.PERSISTENT_ONGOING_NOTIF_ID, getNotification(callsign));
        pilotAsyncTask = new PilotForegroundAsyncTask(this);
        pilotAsyncTask.execute(callsign);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
```

I can confirm that the `AsyncTask` keeps running as I get the respective tracing (periodically perform an action, sleep for 30 secs and repeat).

My question is why in the "Running Services" when running on a real device - I have tried on Galaxy S7 Oreo - I do not see my service in the "running services" inside developer options. I see the process (even if I kill the initiating Activity), but not the Service.

On the simulator (same API level), it works fine most of the times. Sometimes it is not shown there either.

I have checked [a relevant question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436436/android-service-is-running-but-it-doesnt-show-up-in-settings-running-servic) but I am not using `IntentService`. I am extending a good old `Service`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your app running in background?

Comment: I have tried looking at the running services both with my app (activity) running and closed. In both cases I see the process running (which is expected as the service is still running as a foreground service), but I do not see the service listed in the running services.

Comment: I have the same issue. My Service is START_STICKY and I stop it when the user swipes the Activity away, but it restarts itself. The weird thing is, the BroadcastReceivers in the Service don't work, but the listeners do.